# Plotting in R multiple graphs without spaces

Tags: r, graph

I’m aware that how to plot multiple graphs in a same window has been solved already and it’s pretty straight forward. But I can’t find how to remove the space between the different graphs.

I use this script to arrange these three graphs in the same window:

```
mat<-(matrix(1:3,ncol=3))
layout(mat,widths = rep.int(1, ncol(mat)),heights = rep.int(1,nrow(mat)),respect =F)
layout.show(n = 3)
```

With this script I can generate this graph:
[These three violin plots where obtained from a large dataset. I don’t publish the script to get them since I think is not relevant for the purpose of this question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZVDO.jpg)

As you can see this figure can be improved. First the labels at the x-axis are cut from the figure, I don’t know why this is happening. Also I want to remove the space between the three plots. Thanks!

Comment: have a look at `?par` and then search for `mar`.

Comment: Thanks Vandenman. Yes I took a look at par and mar. But I read that I cant use layout() with par(). Neither I knew that I can do this just with par

Comment: You should use not only `mar` but also outer margin, `oma` because 1st graph needs left space but 2nd and 3rd don't. `mar` and `oma` are compatible with `layout()`. Let's try `par(mar=c(4, 0.2, 2, 0.2), oma=c(0, 4, 0, 0.5))`.

Comment: Fantastic cuttlefish44! Thanks